# Как в Django передавать переменные, функциии отслежить это

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте есть Django проект, и я хочу чтобы в первое поле пользователь вводил количество примеров, во второе сложность, и как только он нажал кнопку отправить, вызывался python скрипт. Данный скрипт написан. Затем выскакивают примеры на сайте, и пользователь в форму которая будет ниже вводит ответ, и опять же это всё отправляется в python скрипт, и он выдает информацию от туда.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вот сюда надо вводить ответ, и после нажатия кнопки отправить, что бы данные проверки выдались на сайт.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажи свой питон скрипт пожалуйста

Comment: Он не вмещается там короче главная функция main и 4 маленькие, и выше этих функций есть 2 перменные примерно такая структура

Answer (score 1):

Как может быть задача представлена?

1. У вас есть Model, Template и View (про MTV можно почитать [здесь](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/faq/general/))
2. У вас есть некоторая логика, которая должна быть реализована
3. У вас возникает вопрос: как она должна быть реализована, или куда размещать логику, или как с ней обращаться?

Итак, есть несколько вариантов решения данной задачи. В основном в учебниках по Django рассматривается вариант размещения логики во `Views.py`.

Например, `views.py`:

```
def detail(request):
    if request.method == "POST": # при методе post из template
         data = request.POST     # сохраним все переданные данные в переменную
         any_function(data)      # вызовем какую-то функцию/логику с данными
         amount = data["how_many"]  # например получим количество вопросов
         context = {"amount":amount}
         return render(request, "answers.html", context)
    questions = create_questions()  # вне метода post, т.е. то, что передаем в template
    context = {"questions":questions} # вот здесь передаем в template какие то вопросы
    return render(request, "detail.html", context)
```

Далее в самом template, то есть в неком html файле мы можем обратиться к переменной `questions`

Например, `detail.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Questions</title>    
</head>
<body>
    {{questions}}
</body>
```

Т. е. вы передаете некую переменную, которая может содержать одно значение или итерируемое содержание массива и проч.
Необходимо понимать, что это просто пример для объяснения реализации и логики. Т. е. html файл не содержит метода `post` например или во `views.py` вы не найдете какой либо формы. Это сделано намеренно, чтобы сократить количество строк кода.

Следующий вариант. Можно разместить всю логику в моделях. Т.е. при создании классов модели можно определять методы в самом классе в `models.py`. Такая реализация во многих случаях очень поленза и решает много вопросов таких как читабельность, понятность и обслуживание кода.

Можно использовать js на стороне клиента для реализации некоторой логики. Например, во `views.py` в переменной `context` вы передаете объект модели (некий QuerySet - итерируемый объект или просто экземпляр класса). И организуете работу с этими данными на стороне клиента через javascript. В действительности не очень хорошее решение!

Куда еще прикрепить обработку данных с template/формы? А, почему бы и не в самом `forms.py`. Такое решение тоже имеет место быть. А, еще и в менеджерах можно использовать!

Итак, что же выбрать и как поступить!?
Если ваша логика завязана на `request`, то самый первый вариант с `views.py` вполне подходит!

А, далее смотрите сами, но мой личный топ выглядит так, в порядке приоритета:

1. `models.py`
2. `forms.py`
3. менеджеры

Хотя тут можно спорить)
Если, что то не понятно, то я могу ответить в комментариях. Уточняйте

Comment: Привет, спасибо тебе за ответ, вот есть несколько уточнений.

Как она должна быть реализована, или куда размещать логику, или как с ней обращаться? 
Вот ещё на эти 3 вопроса ответить надо(твои вопросяы), я новичёк поэтому вопросы тупые немного а в интренете я не как не могу найти то, что мне нужно или нахожу  но ничего не могу понять

Comment: Ну у меня столько вопрсов, можешь пожалуйста дать любую соц.сеть свою которую удобно, и если найдёшь время созвонимся, я тебе покажу свой скрипт и  проект и что я хочу сделать.

Comment: с радостью бы поделился с вами знаниями, но время ценнейший ресурс. Я могу отвеить на все ваши вопросы в рамках данного ресурса

Comment: Ну давайте начнем с того, где мне хранить свой python скрипт и как его подставить туда, куда вы показали

Comment: В папке проекта django создаёте папку с названием logic или bislogic. Пишете скрипт туда. Затем во views.py подключаете стандартной командой импорта `from logic import any_script`

Comment: Хорошо теперь там выше на скрине у меня есть 2 поля 1. "Введите кол-во" 2. "Введите сложность", В скрипте у меня есть переменные  1. "count_example = input("Введите кол-во примеров: ")" 2. difficulty = input("Введите сложность примеров от 1 до 3: ").

Мне надо в первое поле подключить count_example, во второе difficulty, и после нажатия кнопки "Отправить", на сайт выводилась то, что находится в скрипте.

Comment: Не хочу вас тревожить, но ответ на данный вопрос есть?

Comment: Есть, конечно. Пропустил ваше сообщение. Во-первых, уберите все input'ы в скриптах. Они вам не понадобятся. Используйте объекты класса или переменные для работы с информацией. Как это работает. 1. Есть форма (она есть?) 2. В форму вводите переменные. 3. Во `views.py` смотрите под `if`есть проверка метода, т.е. при нажатие на кнопку отправить у вас должен срабатывать метод `post`. 4. И если это метод `post` тогда сработает то, что в условии в том числе и перенаправление на другую страницу с той информацией которую вы определите в `answers.html`

Comment: Дмитрий, я только начинающий программист, у меня есть некоторые проблемы в понимании того, что вы пишите, давай я оплачу ваше ценное время, а вы мне расскажете все по "Демонстрации экрана".

Comment: в виде исключения и пока жду самолет у меня есть один час вам что то разъяснить. Мои условия: 1. После этого вы прочитаете книгу по Python и разберетесь. 2. Мне не нужны деньги, но вы поможете кому то еще. Телега?

Comment: Хорошо, я так понимаю моё время истекло?

Comment: Если найдете ещё время, пожалуйста сообщите я просто уже с ума схожу с этим вопросом, и решил просто лежать на кровати, и припустил ваш ответ, поэтому если вы готовы выделить время просто скажите, когда и во сколько

Comment: https://t.me/Danberl Вот телеграм.

Comment: Я спать если что ушёл, телега сверху